# How to insert space between text and icon in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use of bootstrap in my website .When I add **glyphicon glyphicon-user** class to the a tags icons appear with out any space .Please advice

```
<a style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; border-left-width: 10px; border-left-style: solid; margin-left: 10px;" id="dnn_dnnUser_enhancedRegisterLink" title="ثبت‌نام" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" rel="nofollow" >ثبت‌نام</a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put `&nbsp;` between the text and icon.

Example:

```
<a style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; border-left-width: 10px; border-left-style: solid; margin-left: 10px;" id="dnn_dnnUser_enhancedRegisterLink" title="ثبت‌نام"  rel="nofollow" >
    ثبت‌نام &nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
</a>
```

A whitespace will do also

```
<a style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; border-left-width: 10px; border-left-style: solid; margin-left: 10px;" id="dnn_dnnUser_enhancedRegisterLink" title="ثبت‌نام"  rel="nofollow" >
    ثبت‌نام <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
</a>
```

**EDIT:**

As your comment below that you can't add additional tags inside the `a` tag, you can actually add an `&nbsp;` or a whitespace but using your code, the icon is placed on the left not on the right as the image shows.

Using your code add an `&nbsp;` or a whitespace before the text but the icon is on the left.

```
<a style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; border-left-width: 10px; border-left-style: solid; margin-left: 10px;" id="dnn_dnnUser_enhancedRegisterLink" title="ثبت‌نام" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" rel="nofollow" >&nbsp;ثبت‌نام</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the text is to the left, how about adding style="padding-left:10px" to your span?

```
<p>Envelope icon as a link:
    <a href="#">
      <span style="padding-left:10px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
    </a>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two spans inside the anchor tag, one for holding your text, and one for the glyphicon:

```
<a>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="margin-right: 10px"></span>
    <span>your text</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I can not add any tags into a tag .because  I use dotnetnuke and if I add any tags into hyperlink control get error.This a tag is asp hyperlink control

Comment: It doesn't make any notable difference for me.